# 2D Rectangle Rotation GLFW C++ not working as intended

Tags: c++, rotation, glfw, rectangles

I am trying to use GLFW to rotate around the Z axis in 2D space. After scouring forums i found a solution that i implemented as follows:

```
float _FToRadians(float f)
    {
        return (f * C_PI) / 180.0f;
    }
void _RotateVec2(fvec2 &c1, fvec2 pivot, float rotation)
    {
        rotation = _FToRadians(rotation);
        c1.x = pivot.x + cos(rotation) * (c1.x - pivot.x) - sin(rotation) * (c1.y - pivot.y);
        c1.y = pivot.y + sin(rotation) * (c1.x - pivot.x) + cos(rotation) * (c1.y - pivot.y); 
    }
```

And i use the function in the `_DrawRect()` function here:

```
CM_GRAPHICS void _DrawRect(fvec2 start, fvec2 end, const RectOptions &options, const Color &color = CWHITE)
    {
        fvec2 p2 = {end.x, start.y}, p4 = {start.x, end.y};
        glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        std::cout << options.rotation.x << ',' << options.rotation.y << ',' << options.rotation.z << '\n';
        glColor4f(color.r, color.g, color.b, color.a);
        if (options.rotation.z != 0)
        {
            fvec2 rc = {(start.x + end.x) / 2, (start.y + end.y) / 2};
            _RotateVec2(p2, rc, options.rotation.z);
            _RotateVec2(p4, rc, options.rotation.z);
            _RotateVec2(start, rc, options.rotation.z);
            _RotateVec2(end, rc, options.rotation.z);

        }
        glVertex2f(start.x, start.y);

        glVertex2f(p2.x, p2.y);

        glVertex2f(end.x, end.y);

        glVertex2f(p4.x, p4.y);
        glEnd();
    }
```

Upon testing this, for some reason my points are rotating around the x and y axis, and are not behaving normally. I assume this code qualifies for a minimal reproducible example, where `fvec2` is a struct wrapper for a float vec2.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A general formula for affine transformations in 2D is:

```
T * C * R * S * -C
```

where

T: translation (object position)
C: center (pivot point)
R: rotation (around z-axis)
S: scale

If you're not interested in translation and scale (as in your example), set them to identity and the formula gets reduced to:

```
C * R * -C
```

A 3x3 translation matrix looks like

```
1  0  x
0  1  y
0  0  1
```

A 3x3 rotation matrix (z-rotation) looks like

```
c -s  0
s  c  0
0  0  1
```

where

c = cos(rad)
s = sin(rad)

In legacy OpenGL, you would do

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();

glTranslatef(pivot_x, pivot_y, 0);
glRotatef(angle, 0, 0, 1); //rotate around z-axis - angle in radians
glTranslatef(-pivot_x, -pivot_y, 0);
```

If you don't want to use OpenGL for that, then you have to do the matrix multiplications by hand and multiply each vertex coord by the resulting transformation matrix.

**Hint:** if you do the calculations on paper, you'll realize that the zeros in the initial matrices cancel some (unnecessary) operations.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I am trying to impl your gl example here however my shape isn't rotating at all now.
[https://pastebin.com/dtZYLk1E](https://pastebin.com/dtZYLk1E)

i have tried switching the order of the `gl` functions, but the rect does not want to rotate.

Comment: I am not that fluid in legacy OpenGL, but between `glBegin` and `glEnd` only a subset of `gl` commands can be used (see [here](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glBegin.xml)). Another topic is `options.rotation.z`, does this value gets consecutively increased or is it a delta value? In the latter case, you'll always have the same rotation.

Comment: Try to invoke the transformation commands first, then `glBegin` then `glColor4f` then the `glVertex2f` commands and lastly `glEnd`.